# Global mouse events

Tags: c#, events, mouseevent

Hallo,

I am trying to keep track of the mouse position and also its delta position. Is there any nicer way of doing this then implementing all the mouse events for all my forms in my window?

The problem with using the MouseMove event is that as soon as the mouse moves outside of the form it stops working properly. Implementing the mouseEnter, mouseLeave improves it somewhat, but it does still not feel perfect. Any ideas?

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

You have to handle lower level windows events.

Check out this example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx